# How come my LC-3 Program results in an infinite loop?

Tags: assembly, lc3

My JSR calls subroutines that function as intended, however, when I test my program, it is stuck in an infinite loop, I am quite unsure why. Can someone please point me into the correct direction?

Here is what the subroutine is supposed to do:

```
 Input: NUM     (r0, a positive integer)
 Output: STEPS  (r1, the required number of steps for calculation)

 STEPS = 0

 while NUM is not equal to 1:
 if NUM is even -> reduce NUM to NUM/2
 if NUM is odd  -> increase NUM to 3 * NUM + 1
 increment STEPS by 1
```

Here is my subroutine:

```
AND R1, R1, #0             ; INSTANTIATING R1 TO 0 TO RESOLVE REG CONFLICT
ST R0, R0SAVE      
ST R1, R1SAVE

NUM1LOOP  LD R1, R1SAVE
ADD R1, R1, #1
ST R1, R1SAVE
LD R1, ONE               ;Loads 1 into R1 to compare to N
NOT R1, R1
ADD R1, R1, #1
ADD R0 R0, R1        ; CHECKS TO SEE IF N >=1
BRz DONE             ; IF N = 0, N IS 1 AND NEEDS TO STOP LOOP, ELSE CONT.

CHECKEO      AND R0, R1, #1
BRz DIV2E
AND R1, R1,  #0
JSR MUL3ADD1
ST R1, R1JSR
ST R0, R1JSR
BRnzp NUM1LOOP




DIV2E       AND R1, R1,  #0
JSR  DIVIDEBY2
ST R1, R1JSR
ST R0, R1JSR
BRnzp NUM1LOOP      
    
DONE         LD R1, R1SAVE


R1JSR      .BLKW #1
R0SAVE .BLKW #1
R1SAVE .BLKW #1
ONE .FILL #1
RET
```

Comment: For one thing, your `RET`  at the end is in the wrong place, you probably wanted it after the `LD R1, R1SAVE`. As it is, you have a bunch of data in the execution path. Also it's unclear what `R1JSR` is supposed to be and why you store both `R1` and `R0` in there which is pretty pointless. Anyway, use your simulator to single step the code so you can see why it goes into an endless loop.

Comment: Doesnt RET end the subroutine? R1JSR is the value stored into the R1 register following the JSR call, that way I can store that value into R0 to check if n!=0

Comment: Yes, `RET` returns from the subroutine but not if you have data in the middle. You still write two things into `R1JSR`. Also you never read from it so it's useless.

Comment: Is there any way I can contact you? I have updated my R1JSR to Load into R0 and st that value into R0SAVE to act as the new N value for this problem.